# ggplot opening new window

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I am trying to generate a graph in ggplot2, but instead of showing up in the plots window it opens a new window named "R Graphics: Device 2 (ACTIVE)". This prevents me from resizing the graph and saving it in my desired size. I have tried calling dev.off() and dev.cur(), but they return null device 1, which seems correct. Does anyone know how to return it to the plots window? 
I am using R 3.4, RStudio 1.0.136, and Windows 10.

Comment: Use ggsave for exporting plots to a file. You don't provide sufficient information to diagnose why a new graphics window is opened.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) using minimal data/code to cause the behavior.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are running that makes this happen?

Comment: graphical output in R3.4 has some problems in Rstudio 1.0.136. I'd suggest you to update to v1.0.143 to see if it solves your problem.